# How can I add a Clear Button to my Calculator app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, calculator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBbkg.png)I'm a beginner and made a prototype of a calculator app in Xcode. It works great. But to make it more easier to use and add features I thought of adding a Clear Button too. I need help in doing that with my existing code. Please, if possible, give me all steps in detail.

The Code-
The User Interface-
How can I add a All Clear Button to it so the displayed number is 0?

Comment: In order to ask a good question you should show what you have already, what you have tried and exactly the issue your having with this problem. You must of added buttons for the numbers already, just add another one that clears the value

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the given below code**

@IBAction func ClearButtonAction(sender: AnyObject)
{

```
your_TextfieldName.text = ""
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"where Textfield is Outlet Of Your Textfield "

```
@IBAction func Tap_Save(_ sender: UIButton)

{ 
    TextField.text = " "

}
```